# Is the rel attribute necessary in HTML 5 to have with the link element?

Tags: html

Is the rel attribute necessary in HTML 5 to have with the link element, or is it optional?

Comment: Most of the Browsers don't require it :)

Comment: Will the page still work? Most likely. Is it fully valid HTML? No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-link-element):

> A link element must have either a rel attribute or an itemprop attribute, but not both.

Comment: The W3C Markup Validation Service: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input makes it seems like that is required in HTML5 because it will mark the HTML5 document invalid if we do not use, which differs from the specs. @Quentin

Comment: @lisatran — Oh, how I hate the HTML 5 specification. It's much harder to read than the HTML 4 one. Updated with some more information further along in that section.